# Node Streams - Pushing to Read unintentionally splits into 3 Write streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, json2csv

**Goal:** Objects will be pushed to a readable stream and then saved in a separate .csv depending on what channel (Email, Push, In-App) they come from.

**Problem:** I am unable to separate out the streams in to different .pipe() "lines" so all .csv logs receive only their channel specific event objects. But in the current iteration all of the .csv files created by the Writestream are receiving the event objects from all channels.

**Questions:** 
Can I dynamically create the multiple channel "pipe() lines" in the setup() function programmatically or is the current way I am approaching this correct?

Is this manual creation of the "pipe() lines" the reason all of the .csv's are being populated with events?  Can this be solved with one "pipe() line" and dynamic routing?

**A brief explanation of the code below:**

*setup()* calls *makeStreams()* - creates an object with a Readable and a Writable (rotating file system Writable stream) (setup() is an unnecessary function right now but will hold more setup tasks later.)

*pushStream()* is called when an inbound event occurs and pushes an object like: {Email: {queryParam:1, queryParam:2, etc.}} The event is sorted by the highest level obj (in this case "Email") and then is pushed to the correct writable stream which in theory should be ported to the correct writable stream. 
Unfortunately this isn't the case, it's sending the event object to all of the writable streams. How can I send it to only the correct stream?

**CODE**:

```
const Readable = require('stream').Readable
const Json2csvTransform = require('json2csv').Transform;
var rfs = require("rotating-file-stream");

const channelTypes = ['Push Notification', 'Email', 'In-app Message']
var streamArr = setup(channelTypes);
const opts = {};
const transformOpts = {
    objectMode: true
};

const json2csv = new Json2csvTransform(opts, transformOpts);

function setup(list) {
    console.log("Setting up streams...")
    streamArr = makeStreams(list) //makes streams out of each endpoint
    return streamArr
}

//Stream Builder for Logging Based Upon Channel Name
function makeStreams(listArray) {
    listArray = ['Push Notification', 'Email', 'In-app Message']
    var length = listArray.length
    var streamObjs = {}
    for (var name = 0; name < length; name++) {
        var fileName = listArray[name] + '.csv'
        const readStream = new Readable({
            objectMode: true,
            read() {}
        })
        const writeStream = rfs(fileName, {
            size: "50M", // rotate every 50 MegaBytes written
            interval: "1d" // rotate daily
            //compress: "gzip" // compress rotated files
        });

        var objName = listArray[name]
        var obj = {
            instream: readStream,
            outstream: writeStream
        }
        streamObjs[objName] = obj
    }
    return streamObjs
}

function pushStream(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj)

        if (streamArr[keys]) {
        streamArr[keys].instream.push(obj[keys])
    } else {
        console.log("event without a matching channel error")
    }
}

//Had to make each pipe line here manually. Can this be improved? Is it the reason all of the files are receiving all events?
streamArr['Email'].instream.pipe(json2csv).pipe(streamArr['Email'].outstream)
streamArr['In-app Message'].instream.pipe(json2csv).pipe(streamArr['In-app Message'].outstream)
streamArr['Push Notification'].instream.pipe(json2csv).pipe(streamArr['Push Notification'].outstream)

module.exports = {
    makeStreams,
    pushStream,
    setup
}
```